# Symfony2 Collections. Relations in controller

Tags: php, symfony, collections

So, I have 3 Entities. All are related like it is shown on the
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhJyi.jpg)

And I have this code in controller

```
/**
* After clicking the link at our index page we are getting to the show page
* where the user can pass the test
*/
public function showAction($id) 
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // Here we get out test's ID
    $test = $em->getRepository('TestprojectTestManagerBundle:Test')->find($id);
    // Then we get our questions information according to previously chosen test's ID 
    $questions = $em->getRepository('TestprojectTestManagerBundle:Question')->findBy(
        array('test'=>$test),
        array('question'=>'ASC')
        );
    // Here I tried to do the same with my answers, i.e. getting answers according to the current question
    // But faild. $questions is all questions of our test. So, we get all answers of all questions of our test.
    // Didn't figured out how to solve this.
    $answers = $em->getRepository('TestprojectTestManagerBundle:Answer')->findBy(
        array('questions'=>$questions),
        array('answer'=>'ASC')
        );
    return $this->render('TestprojectTestManagerBundle:Test:show.html.twig', array(
        'test'=>$test,
        'questions'=>$questions,
        'answers'=>$answers,

    ));
}
```

Then I'm trying to create a page in show.html.twig

```
<ul>
    {% for question in questions %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ question.question }}</p>
            {% if question.toa == 'select' %}

            <form>
            {% for answer in answers %}
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{ answer.answer }}">{{ answer.answer }}</input><br>
            {% endfor %}
            </form>

            {% endif %}

            {% if question.toa == 'check' %}

            <form>
            {% for answer in answers %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer{{ answer.id }}" value="{{ answer.answer }}">{{ answer.answer }}</input><br>
            {% endfor %}
            </form>

            {% endif %}

            {% if question.toa == 'textfield' %}

            <form>
            {% for answer in answers %}
            <input type="text" name="answer{{ answer.id }}"><br>
            {% endfor %}
            </form>

            {% endif %}

        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So, I'm expecting to get something like this:

```
Test1
 Question 1
  Q1.Answer 1
  Q1.Answer 2
 Question 2
  Q2.Answer 1
  Q2.Answer 2
```

But I'm getting this

```
Test1
 Question 1
  Q1.Answer 1
  Q1.Answer 2
  Q2.Answer 1
  Q2.Answer 2
 Question 2
  Q1.Answer 1
  Q1.Answer 2
  Q2.Answer 1
  Q2.Answer 2
```

How can I make my answers be shown according to the question_id they are related to?
I also tried to call for question_id and try to make an if statement in my twig template. Like if question.id == answer.question_id then show answer.answer. But it didn't work. It says that question_id doesn't exist. Though it exists in my database!
In my entities there are:

```
//in answer entity
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $questions;
//in question entity
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="questions", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
*/
protected $answers;
```

So, I tried to compare question.id and answer.questions. But it says

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Object of class Testproject\TestManagerBundle\Entity\Question could not be converted to int") in TestprojectTestManagerBundle:Test:show.html.twig at line 16.

I also tried {% if question.answers == answer.questions %} and it let rendering goes well, but it returns false.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.
P.S. sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{% if question.id == answer.questions.id %}`

You should have write

`//in answer entity
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $question; // not questions because its ManyToOne`

Then in the template it becomes

`{% if question.id == answer.question.id %}`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked! Oh my God! I didn't expect that 's' would make a difference. Thank you!

Comment: I've just checked that 's' doesn't make difference indeed. Just I needed to write in twig answer.questions.id. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if doctrine generated the entities, it removes underscores. Did you try question.id == answer.questionId? And also, question is not related to question_id in your database.

Comment: Ah, there was a mistake in my description. Of course I compared question.id with answer.question_id. Thank you for your suggestion. I tried answer.questionId and answer.questionid but this didn't work. It says Method "questionid" for object "Testproject\TestManagerBundle\Entity\Answer" does not exist in TestprojectTestManagerBundle:Test:show.html.twig at line 16